# free tool to convert Outlook .pst files to Linux email (Maildir/MH/mbox)

Tags: email, outlook

I have a couple of Outlook `.pst` files that I want to convert to some other format, preferably Maildir or MH.

Both `readpst` and `pffexport` produce strange incorrect output. For example, there is a sequence A B C that I recognise and that might be the title of an email or a folder (cannot remember), but in the output it becomes nested file folders

```
A
  B
    C
```

Some folders are empty, most of the actual mail folders are sub-folders of the Inbox in the output, whereas originally I had no nested folders at all, and so on. Very unsatisfactory.

Comment: if you still have a windows-machine with outlook installed use it and [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net) to import your messages into Thunderbird. - depending on your settings, Thunderbird uses `mbox` or `Maildir` as internal format in its [profile folder](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data).

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the OS for the software, but for Windows, you can try **PST to Maildir Converter**, available here free:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/pst-to-maildir-f02b468a

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this does not seem to be free, and also it displays the same problem with the incorrect structure. I'm beginning to think maybe my files were messed up when they were created.